# Shared variable among various threads in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I've requirement to calculate the total number of post requests sent to a server. My script uses a thread per JSON file which contains post data. Below is the rough code snippet.

```
statistics = 0

def load_from_file(some_arguments, filename):
    data_list = json.loads(open(filename).read())
    url = address + getUrl(filename, config)
    for data in data_list.get("results"):
        statistics += 1 
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers,
                          auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

def load_from_directory(some_arguments, directory):
    pool = mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count() * 2)
    func = partial(load_from_file, some_arguments)
    file_list = [f for f in listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, f))]
    pool.map(func, [join(directory, f) for f in file_list ])
    pool.close() 
    pool.join() 

    print "total post requests", statistics
```

I want to print the total number of post requests processed using this script. Is it the right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing memory is not so simple when using multiprocesses. I'm not seeing the need to use the multiprocessing module instead of threading. Multiprocessing is mostly used as a workaround for the Global interpreter lock.

In your example you are using IO bound operations which probably won't ever reach full CPU time. If you insist on using multiprocess instead of threading I suggest to take a look at [exchanging-objects-between-processes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes).

Otherwise using `threading` you can share the global `statistics` variable between threads.

```
import threading

statistics = 0

def load_from_file(some_arguments, filename):
    global statistics
    data_list = json.loads(open(filename).read())
    url = address + getUrl(filename, config)
    for data in data_list.get("results"):
        statistics += 1
        r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers,
                        auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password))

def load_from_directory(some_arguments, directory):
    threads = []
    func = partial(load_from_file, some_arguments)

    file_list = [f for f in listdir(directory) if isfile(join(directory, f))]

    for f in file_list:
        t = threading.Thread(target=func, args=(join(directory, f)))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    #Wait for threads to finish
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()

    print "total post requests", statistics
```

*Note: This currently simultaneously spawns threads based on the number of files in the directory. You might want to implement some kind of throttling for optimal performance.*

Comment: Adding print "current running thread", print threading.current_thread().getName() in load_from_file method, prints current running thread MainThread
current running thread MainThread
current running thread. I don't see the usage and essence of multi threading here. This script is not making use of multiple threads.

Comment: Apologies. The start and join should be called in seperate loops. Eg: start all threads, once they have started call join() on them all to block until they are finished. I've edited the code.